# Вопрос по работе Valgrind

Tags: отладка, память, c, valgrind

Всем добрый день!
Пытаюсь разобраться с Valgrind (Memcheck), возникла пара вопросов:

1. (**Отредактирован**) При запуске приложения под Valgrind функция *sigprocmask()* завершается с ошибкой, в то время, как при обычном запуске работает и возвращает валидное значение. С чем это может быть связано?
2. Если кто может, объясните, пожалуйста, на пальцах, что означает *"still reachable"* в результатах работы Valgrind? Из прочтенного - это еще доступные ресурсы, которые могут быть освобождены, однако, если учесть, что демон досрочно завершился, почему они доступны? Это могут быть переменные, объявленные в данном модуле как *extern*?

Заранее извиняюсь, если вопросы покажутся праздными, осваиваю Valgrind c наскока в короткий срок, хочется разобраться. Не откажусь от ссылок на подробную информацию, освещающую эти вопросы.

Comment: первый вопрос неактуален : судя по логам, Valgrind каким-то образом мешает нормально завершиться функции *sigpromask()* (без Valgrind работает корректно, с Valgrind возвращает -1), может кто сталкивался с подобным?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Приложение должно работать, как обычно, но медленнее. Но довольно часто при использовании valgrind проявляют себя ошибки, которые в обычной программе остались незамеченными (из-за случайности). Например, попытка использования памяти, которую только что освободили.
2. still reachable означает, что к моменту завершения программы вы не сделали delete для каких-то указателей, но сами указатели еще остались (т.е. можно было освободить память). Это может быть из-за того, что ваша программа упала, а не завершилась нормально

Добавлено:

Не имеет значения, каким этот показатель будет после завершения программы, потому что вся выделенная память все равно вернется операционной системе. Но то, что где-то в программе накопилась неучтенная память -- не очень хорошо.

Пример: демон раз в N секунд выполняет какое-то действие. Допустим, он должен хранить историю последних десяти действий. Тогда у него будет такой алгоритм работы:

1. Что-то сделать.
2. Если записей больше десяти, удалить одну
3. Добавить запись о текущем действии в историю

Если случайно сделать ошибку во втором пункте, история (и вообще, количество выделенной программе памяти) будет бесконечно расти. Но вся эта память будет still reacable, потому что, теоретически, ее можно освободить.

Я бы начал не с этого. Лучше сначала написать небольшой скрипт, который будет раз в N секунд читать данные (в основном, VmRSS) из [/proc/[pid]/status](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) и дал бы программе поработать какое-то время. Потом строите график, и все сразу становится видно: если портебление памяти растет, надо браться за valgrind и искать причины, если достаточно стабильно -- фиг с ним.

Comment: спасибо. хотелось бы узнать подробнее про still reachable, - при нормальном завершении программы и отсутствии утечек, этот показатель обязан быть равен 0, или имеются еще какие-то варианты? Насколько вообще он критичен?

Comment: многовато текста получилось, проапдейтил ответ :)

Answer (score 0):

Разобралась с первым вопросом, может кому-нибудь пригодится :
функция *sigprocmask()* в моем случае использовалась для получения текущего значения маски сигналов, в качестве первого аргумента *how* я передавала в нее 0 (аналогично примерам из книг Р. Стивенса), вторым - NULL, третьим - указатель для сохранения текущей маски. Однако, как выяснилось, Valgrind нулевого значения аргумента *how* не понимает (видимо анализирует его, хотя в данном случае должен бы игнорировать), и функция завершается с ошибкой. Если изменить значение этого аргумента на любое допустимое(*SIG_BLOCK, SIG_UNBLOCK, SIG_SETMASK*),- функция успешно возвращает маску сигналов и программа продолжает свое выполнение под Valgrind.